# AppEngine Safari "Failed to load resource: Frame load interrupted" (but file still downloads)

Tags: google-app-engine, safari, google-cloud-storage, google-app-engine-php

I'm building a signed url to download a Google Cloud Storage File via Google App Engine and I get the following error:

> http://storage.googleapis.com/BUCKET/file?GoogleAccessId=name@appspot.gserviceaccount.com&Expires=1470185565&Signature=SIGNATURE&response-content-disposition=attachment;filename=blah.png
>
> Failed to load resource: Frame load interrupted

The weird thing is, the error doesn't hinder anything. The file still downloads, even in Safari - and I only get the error in Safari.

I am just confused on why this error is happening if the URL works and the file downloads.